# How can I place an order using AJAX in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am using Woocommerce on a locally hosted WordPress.

I would like the 'Place order' button in the order review section/checkout section of Woocommerce to process the order using AJAX (so that the order details are added to the database without refreshing the page).

I can't seem to find any information on this anywhere. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've got the order details updating using AJAX with some code I copied from another post. I don't know where to begin with AJAX and placing an order. I did a lot of googling and can't find ANYTHING on AJAX and order placing in Woocommerce - I would have thought this would have been a really common thing... If you can point me in the direction of out there I would be grateful

Comment: Do you have any experience in programming?

Comment: Some experience, mainly with JS

Comment: In WooCommerce normal behavior is when you click on the place order button on checkout ajax will be called. so I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for your reply - but I don't fully understand. WooCommerce's normal behaviour doesn't use ajax, when I click the 'Place order' button it redirects to the "Order received" page. Is it possible, when the 'Place order' button is pressed, for the data to be submitted without the page refreshing or redirecting?

Comment: Yes, it's possible but it requires custom code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add an eventlistener to the "Place order" button's click event, and prevent the default behaviour. Then use Ajax to make a POST request to the WooCommemerce REST API's [order endpoint](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-an-order%5D). The documentation contains all the information needed to set it up, and examples of such requests.

You can use the response to update your page with relevant information.